# Mass update product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

[M1]

I created a custom attribute with name 'Warranty'. we have over 2000 products listed and we would like to mass update 'warranty' attribute as the warranty for all products is the same, however, when I'm going to Catalog > Products > Select All > Update Attributes, I cannot see warranty attribute in the list of attributes that could be mass updated. I need to bring this custom attribute in that list so that I can bulk update it. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is warranty "static" type attribute?
If yes then static attributes should not appear on update attribute screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a mixture of product types? For example try selecting all simples first and doing a mass update to see if the option is there. Then try a different type. If the option is missing potentially you've got an attribute locked to a particular type. That's enough for it to not show in the mass update screen. In which case you might need to spend more time checking over how the attribute is configured.